# How can I check if external site framekiller is active?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a portion in my site wherein users can add HTML just by providing the link and the content will be loaded in an iframe.

However, there are sites where framekiller is enabled. For those sites, I plan not to render it and add an external link and a note to users but I'm unable to detect if the external site's framekiller is active or not.

I already tried reading the contents by using Nokogiri and native `open().read`, but this failed since it returns results and the problem is on DOM loading part.

I also tried checking the iframe contentWindow and contentDocument but both of them are undefined.

Can someone please help me? JavaScript or Ruby code would help.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)." So, with that in mind, show us what you tried, along with a sample of the HTML.

Comment: The thing you refer to as "frame killer" is just a piece of Javascript which check if current frame is same as parent/top/whatever and if not forces reload on parent frame. I see no viable way to stop such behaviour.